# How to check that the two consecutive words have the same regex pattern

Tags: python, regex

I've tried for several hours but I couldn't reach my goal.

Here is the string:`'Hello world, By The Way stackoverflow is cool place'`.
What I'm looking up for is to match two consecutive words that have the same Regex pattern.

For example I want to replace the words that are consecutive and start with a Capital letter with the string `"xx"`.

So when I applied it to my string the result should be:

`Hello world,xx xx xx stackoverflow is cool place`

Here is my snippet:

```
myString='Hello world,By The Way stackoverflow is cool place'
re.sub(r"[A-Z]\w+","xx",myString)
```

But what I'm getting is:
`'xx world,xx xx xx stackoverflow is cool place'`

Comment: I thought of this: `([A-Z]\S*)(?=\s+[A-Z])` It almost works, except it won't match last words in the chain. Maybe someone else will see a simple fix to this?

Answer (score 1):

Using `regex` module:

```
>>> import regex
>>> text = 'Hello world,By The Way stackoverflow is cool place'
>>> regex.sub(r'\b[A-Z]\w+(?=\s+[A-Z]\w+)|(?<=\b[A-Z]\w+\s+)[A-Z]\w+', 'xx', text)
'Hello world,xx xx xx stackoverflow is cool place'
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to make but I was thrown off by positive lookbehinds not being supported by regexpal, +1

Comment: This doesn't guarantee the word starts with a capital letter.

Comment: why you've used regex module instead of re ? i've tried to install it but a lot of problems popped up

Comment: @EngHamoud Python's default `re` doesn't support variable lookbehinds... anyway `regex` may become a part of python in 3.4 anyway

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this, have the following imports/assignments

```
import re,string

lowercase = string.ascii_lowercase
uppercase = string.ascii_uppercase
punctuation = string.punctuation
digits = string.digits
specials = r'.^+*$\[]|()'
```

Then have a function which creates the pattern represented by a word/fragment of the sentance

```
def getPat(text):
    pattern = r""
    for c in text:
        if c in uppercase:
            pattern += '[A-Z]'
        elif c in lowercase:
            pattern += '[a-z]'
        elif c in digits:
            pattern += '\d'
        else:
            if c in specials:
                pattern += '\%s' % c
            else:
                pattern += c
    return pattern
```

Then you can go over the words and check if their patterns match

```
sentance = 'Hello world, By Hi nI The Way stackoverflow is cool place'.split()
for word,wordNext in zip(sentance,sentance[1:]):
    if getPat(word) == getPat(wordNext):
        print("{0} = {1}".format(word,wordNext))
```

Would produces

```
>>> 
By = Hi
The = Way
```

You could do the replacement by adjusting the loop like so:

```
res = ""
for word,wordNext in zip(sentance,sentance[1:]):
    if getPat(word) == getPat(wordNext):
        print("{0} = {1}".format(word,wordNext))
        res += " xx"*2
    else:
        res += " %s" % word
print(res)
```

Would give:

```
 Hello world, xx xx Hi nI xx xx Way stackoverflow is cool
```